# How to activate application window in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I tried to set window flags:

```
self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
```

it works perfectly but event keyPressEvent doesn't firing. After I activate window (ALT+TAB) event starts and work.

By the way, I tried to activate window with call this event: `self.activateWindow()` but it doesn't work for me.

How to fix it?

full-code:

```
def show(self):
    geometry = QtGui.QApplication.desktop().screenGeometry()
    self.setFixedSize(geometry.width(), geometry.height())
    self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
    self.setWindowOpacity(.3)
    self.setStyleSheet("background: 'black'")

    self.raise_()
    self.show()

def keyPressEvent(self, e):
    key = e.key()
    if key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Escape:
        self.close()
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please include rudimentary code that shows how you invoked the window and connected the key-press event. Also, what is your OS/windowing system, may be important.

Comment: @mdurant, done. OS: Windows.

Comment: self.show() calls self.show()? You should probably show() first (using the superclass's show), then raise(), then activate().

Comment: @mdurant, self.show inherited from QMainWindow. I tried `        self.show()
        self.raise_()
        self.activateWindow()` doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, works fine under linux/cinnamon

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should try is this:

```
self.setFocus(QtCore.Qt.PopupFocusReason)
```

Comment: Thanks. But it doesn't work. I included my full code of application.